# How to solve this Data is null error after extending IdentityUser razor .net6 EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-identity

I extended the IdentityUser in my app:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        public string? PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public Company? Company { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Updated all references replacing IdentityUser to Application and updated the pipeline.

The site runs but logging in gives me this error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)
lambda_method93(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SingleQueryResultCoordinator )
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>.FindByNameAsync(string userName)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
WebRazor.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnPostAsync(string returnUrl) in Login.cshtml.cs
ERROR -> +   115 var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

All the parameters in  await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync have appropriate values. It throws at the result as it is null.

Here is the SQL Db

[image]

I have previous migrations and data in the db so I dont want to drop and rebuild unless I really need to.

Anyone have any wisdom here to fix this quickly.

[image]

When I apply the migration adding nullable to the Name I get this message:

[image]

Comment: Side note: you're better off not extending `IdentityUser`. It entangles authentication concerns and business concerns. Create an `ApplicationUser` that refers to ASP.Net's identity users but is a class of its own in your business data/class model.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the username is the same as the email your passing in.  If it's not, that will cause that error as SignInManager.PasswordSignIn works off the username.

Comment: Username, email all the same from identity user.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the connection string is pointing to the same database. I'd also recommend using SQL Profiler to double-check the query being run against the database